# How to calculate a birthday date regardeless of year

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate customer with the account creation date in the next 8 days, so i want to calculate this date using only the day and the month , if the creation anniversary date is in 8 days, i can retrieves these contacts and contact them. 
is there any exemple of query using only month an day to calculate the upcoming date?

thank you

Comment: [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this (tested on PostgresQL, may require some adjustments for other DBs):

```
select * from temp_contacts where
    to_char(date_created, 'MM-dd') = 
      to_char(current_date + interval '8 day', 'MM-dd');
```

For each row it first maps the `date_created` to a string using `MM-dd` format, then does the same to the current date + 8 days and compares the two.
This of course is not using any index, so it will not perform well on a table with large enough size.

Some DBs support creating function based indices. For example PostgresQL or Oracle DB. In MySQL you can achieve the same by creating an auto generated column and indexing on it.